# TUI Text Editing

Tags: c, termcap

Working on C code that reads a line of text and allows cursor movement and editing using TERMCAP routines (similar to the "readline" library).  Question is this: when one or more characters need to be erased from the end of the line, it is more efficient to (1), move the cursor to EOL and issue `\b \b` sequences; or (2), move the cursor to the truncation point and issue a single "erase-to-end-of-line" command?  Not sure how "expensive" the latter command is, especially on a wide terminal.  Anybody know what the tradeoffs/guidelines are?

Comment: Erasing with \b is different than killing to end-of-line. What if there are two words in the same line, and you want to erase some char from the first word? Clearing to the end of line is probably faster (not important in modern hardware), but would erase the second word too.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the output device (terminal), and on how many characters are being erased. Typically, if the device supports an Erase-to-EOL in the first place, it's there because it's faster than doing more than one or two Erase-Single-Character operations.

Unless you're operating over a very slow connection, it probably doesn't matter. Back in the '80s this sort of thing was something of a concern because we were often working over 1200bps connections and the like; that's also why people often eschewed curses(3) and went right to termcap. These days, both communications and output devices are typically so much faster than users' reaction times you can often get away with redrawing the screen entirely.

Out of curiosity, why use termcap at all? It was superseded by terminfo on most UNIXy platforms decades ago. Not to mention the availability of higher-level libraries like curses.

Comment: Good points.  The time it takes to redraw the line over a slow connection would be the only real concern, and that's not likely to be a problem these days.  Just trying to do a little optimizing in the code to minimize cursor movement.  I think I'll use Erase-Single-Character for one character at the end of the line; otherwise, back up and Erase-to-EOL.

Comment: I'm using termcap system calls (which is implemented in the terminfo library under macOS) because I haven't been able to get direct terminfo calls to work yet.  I plan to switch over to terminfo once I figure out what the problem is.  Thanks.